# Construction of an integral $\int^1_0 f(t)dt$ for any cont function $f$

Tags: real-analysis

> We want to construnct a integral $\int^1_0 f(t)dt$ for any continuous function $f$. Let $Y=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the supremum norm. With
>
> $$v_{n,i}(t)=\begin{cases}nt-(i-1)&(i-1)/n<t<i/n\\i+1-nt & i/n\leq t<(1+i)/n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $i=0,1\dots,n$ and let $S_n\subset Y$ be the subspace
>
> $$S_N=\{\sum^n_{i=0}a_iv_{n,i}\mid a_0,a_1\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> and $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n$

How do I prove that if $f\in S$ then $||f||=\max_{i=0\dots n}|a_i|$ and that $S$ is dense in $Y$

I'm not sure how go on about doing it. For the dense part I thought about using for every $f\in Y$ is uniform cont then defining a function $v\in S_n$ s.t $v(i/n)=f(i/n)$ I don't know how to go from here. For the max part could the the fact that we have the supremum norm help?

Comment: I think in your definition of $v_{n,i}(t)$ the first formula should be defined from $(i-1)/n$ to $i/n$ In that way the graph of your $v_{n,i}(t)$ will look like a peak in the interval $[(i-1)/n, (i+1)/n]$, with maximum of 1 at its center.

Comment: @JulianMejia that's correct, a typo. Edited it now

Comment: if we let $t\in[0,1]$ the maximum is at $t=i/n$ but how can I argue with this?

Comment: All I was saying is that for $f=v_{n,i}$, we have that the maximum is 1. Hence, for $f=av_{n,i}$, we have $f(i/n)=a$, and in fact at this point is where you have the maximum of $|f|$, so $\|f\|=|a|$. And in general If $f=\sum{a_i}v_i$ you can check that $f(n/i)=a_i$, so definitely you have that $||f||\geq \max|a_i|$, and then you have to check that in fact $\|f\|\leq \max |a_i|$ by analyzing your function in each subinterval $[1/n, (i+1)/n].$

Comment: you mean $[i/n,(i+1)/n]$ right? I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: Yeah I meant [i/n,i+1/n]. You can post your answer if you completed the problem.

Comment: I still haven't done it yet, thought I had it but i'll just skip it for now